# How to make GUI of process list with wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm trying to make GUI of process list which contains the running proceesses list name, Id and size. I'm using wxpython and I got stucked. Apriciate help!
this is what I wrote until now :

```
import wx
import wmi
wmi_object = wmi.WMI ()
application= wx.App()
frame= wx.Frame(None,title="Process List",size=(500,500))
inside= wx.Panel(frame)
process= wx.StaticText(inside,label="Process Name",pos=(0,0))
id_name= wx.StaticText(inside,label="ID ",pos=(200,0))
size= wx.StaticText(inside,label="Size",pos=(400,0))
x=50
for lines in wmi_object.Win32_Process ():
    line= wx.StaticText(inside,label=str(str(process.ProcessId) + "  " + process.Name + "  " +  str(size) + " kb"),pos=(50,x))
    x+=50

frame.Show(True)
application.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What's the problem? You can use ˋpsutil` to get the list of running processes. Note that GUI already exist for `psutil` that can inspire you.

Comment: can I do it without psutil? On the way I wrote above?

Comment: I don't ear about [wmi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) before.  Only works for Windows. Looks deserted since 2011-04-13. So use  [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/4.3.1) instead. Really.